# can't run commands in bash invoked from emacs shell on windows

Tags: bash, shell, cmd.exe, cygwin, emacs

I invoked "shell" which correctly runs cmd.exe and runs correctly.
However, when I run bash from within that shell, every command gives an error

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.739] (c) Microsoft Corporation.  
All rights reserved.  

c:\tools\Emacs\emacs-28.1>bash  
bash  
ll  
bash: line 1: $'ll\r': command not found  

bash: line 2: $'\r': command not found
```

The 1st command I typed was `ll`. From the error output, we can see that a "\r" is being added to my "`ll`".
the 2nd command I typed was a simple ENTER. From the error output, we can see that a "\r" is being added to my "ENTER".

outside of emacs : When I invoke bash from a cmd.exe shell, everything works as expected.

The bash is from cygwin 64-bit, if that helps and I'm on windows 11 professional.  The emacs was built for windows native (not cygwin or WSL) from http://gnu.bardia.tech/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-28/emacs-28.1-installer.exe.

How should I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Probable** cause:
That terminal sends CR+LF ("`\r\n`" Windows/DOS/...) at line endings,
Bash expects LF only (e.g. Linux convention).

See if you can convince Cygwin-Bash to filter out the `\r` - I can't tell if it is possible.

Other alternative; make emacs launch a more "standard" terminal; e.g. `rxvt` from Cygwin.